# How can I put a newline into a TextBox, which only occurs when the string "CRLF" is received

Tags: c#, textbox, code-behind

How can I put a newline into a TextBox, which only occurs when the string "CRLF" is received

This is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

This is my textbox output at the moment

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHjXv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHjXv.png)]

The line which shows CRLF?J] should be just a blank line.

This is the code I am using.

```
    private void WriteData(string text)
    {
        if (text == "CRLF")
        {               
            serial.DiscardInBuffer();   // clear "CRLF" from serial port buffer
            serial.BaseStream.Flush();
            OutputTextBox.AppendText("\n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            OutputTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
            OutputTextBox.AppendText(text);
            serial.BaseStream.Flush();
            OutputTextBox.AppendText("\n");
        }
    }
```

Any and all help gratefully received.

Comment: Try following code may its helps you 
    
    OutputTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

Comment: Obviously you never get given string (not alone) so comparing doesn't make sens...

Comment: I have edited my question, and added a picture of what I require, hopefully this will explain things better.

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for your comment it set me on the right path, I have answered question.

Comment: @MarkStevens please mark an answer as the solution since it helped you resolve you problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my new code, works fine now, thanks all for contributing @Selvin pointed out the right path with his comment.

```
    private void WriteData(string text)
    {
        string SerialData = text;


        if (SerialData.Contains ("CRLF"))
        {
            serial.DiscardInBuffer();   // clear "CRLF" from serial port buffer
            OutputTextBox.AppendText("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            OutputTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
            OutputTextBox.AppendText(text + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
private void WriteData(string text)
{
    if (text == "CRLF")
    {               
        serial.DiscardInBuffer();   // clear "CRLF" from serial port buffer
    }
    else
    {
        OutputTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
        OutputTextBox.AppendText(text);
    }
    serial.BaseStream.Flush();
    OutputTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this didn't work, this gives the output with a newline between every string received, and still shows CRLF?J] , that was present in my code. I tried to attach a snip, but I can't do that in a comment.

Comment: is it going into if condition for *CRLF*?

Comment: Yes -- I have edited my question, and added a picture of what I require, hopefully this will explain things better.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void WriteData(string text)
{
    if (text == "CRLF")
    {
        serial.DiscardInBuffer();   // clear "CRLF" from serial port buffer
        serial.BaseStream.Flush();
        OutputTextBox.AppendText("\n");  // Add a single newline for the blank line
    }
    else
    {
        OutputTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
        OutputTextBox.AppendText(text + "\n");  // Add a newline after the received text
        serial.BaseStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

In this version of the code, I've made two changes:

In the case where the text is "CRLF", I added a single OutputTextBox.AppendText("\n"); line to add a newline character, which will result in a blank line being added to the TextBox.

In the else case, I modified the OutputTextBox.AppendText(text); line to include a + "\n" at the end. This ensures that a newline character is added after the received text, creating a new line for the next entry.

With these changes, your code will insert a blank line when "CRLF" is received and also properly insert new lines for other text entries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it didn't work.  I have edited my question, and added a picture of what I require, hopefully this will explain things better.